# How to change telephone number, check if shipping country is "India" i want to add +91 before place order only

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, onepage-checkout, billing-address

How to `change telephone number`, check if shipping country is **India** i want to add **+91** `before place order only`.

what i have tryed:

```
/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

`review.save()` is calling when place order.

```
document.getElementById('billing:telephone').value="9123456";
document.getElementById('shipping:telephone').value="91234567";
billingnewsletter();  shipping.save();
```

using sales_order_save_before events:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billingaddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$billingtelephone = $billingaddress->getTelephone();
$billingaddress->setTelephone("31313131");
$billingaddress->save();
```

but it is not setTelephone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below,

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billingaddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$billingtelephone = $billingaddress->getTelephone();
$billingaddress->setTelephone("31313131");
$billingaddress->save();
$quote->setBillingAddress($billingaddress);
$quote->save();
```

======= EDIT ==============

Please use other event `sales_convert_quote_to_order`
and use below code in that observer function

```
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
$billingaddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$billingtelephone = $billingaddress->getTelephone();
$billingaddress->setTelephone("31313131");
$billingaddress->save();
$quote->save();
```

Comment: i tried the above but not saving.

Comment: Please try my updated code with mentioned event